# Fixture.detectChanges behaves in a strange way when I add service to the constructor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a parent component:

```
 @Component({
selector: 'parent-component',
directives: [I18nDirective, child-component],
template: require('./parent.component.html'),
styles: [require('./parent.component.scss')],
})
export class ParentComponent {
}
```

Then I have child component:

```
@Component({
selector: 'child-component',
template: require('./child-component.component.html'),
styles: [require('./child-component.component.scss')]
})
export class ChildComponent {

constructor(private _eventAggregator: EventAggregatorService, private _zone: NgZone) {}
```

In the parent component's html I use: child-component

The problem is in the spec test of child component. They pass when the test is:

```
describe('Center On Me Button', () => {

let fixture;
let nativeElement;
let componentInstance;

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    ChildComponent,
    EventAggregatorService,
    GeoLocationService,
    provide(GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, {useClass: StabGoogleMapsApiWrapper}),
    provide(MapController, {useClass: StabMapControllerService}),
    provide(MapEventsService, {useClass: StabMapEventsService})
]);

beforeEach(injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, GeoLocationService, MapController, EventAggregatorService
    ], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder ) => {

    return tcb
        .createAsync(ChildComponent).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>) => {

            ({nativeElement, componentInstance} = componentFixture);
            fixture = componentFixture;
            componentFixture.detectChanges();
        });

 it('should enable Geolocation button when it is clicked', done => {
    componentInstance.isGeoLocationButtonEnabled = false;
    nativeElement.querySelector('.toggle.fa.fa-crosshairs').click();
    expect(componentInstance.isGeoLocationButtonEnabled).toBe(true);
    done();
});
}));
```

My PROBLEM is that in such a configuration the tests pass. But as soon as I want to add the service instance to the child-component constructor, the test wont pass (it fails in the parent.component.spec) with the following message:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fixture.detectChanges') ... in parent.component.spec.ts
```

All I have done is added the: **private someService: SomeService to the constructor of the child-component.** So I have now:

```
export class ChildComponent {

constructor(private _eventAggregator: EventAggregatorService, private _zone: NgZone, private _someService: SomeService) {}
```

This service I add is added to the providers list at the top level of angular app. Of course I add it to the providers list in the test itself.

When I do this, tests start to fail with the previous message I wrote. Why the heck is that ? I really do not understand this behaviour and resource are limited on this in the network. NO documentation yet.

Comment: Might be https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8867

Comment: This probably is not that case: When I add private _geoLocationService: GeoLocationService, I get the same behaviour and the geolocation service is injected in before each providers without provide.